# React Helmet: Change favicon based on color scheme

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-helmet

Hi is it possible to change the favicon based on the color scheme? I have created this webhook in my SEO component. But it's not changing. The listener is working though.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', e => setDarkMode(e.matches)) return () => {
    window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').removeEventListener('change', e => setDarkMode(e.matches))
  }
}, [])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which part of this useEffect hook are you expecting to change your favicon? Is it `setDarkMode`? Can we see the code? (also, would you mind formatting the code in your question?)